# Java, Sockets, UTF-8, I cannot understand the format

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, inputstreamreader

I am programming using Java for a data acquisition project. I completed the interface to the device part in Python, but it's way too heavy on the processing.

I have been converting it to Java (newbie!) and was able to send and receive the setup data, which are all ASCII.

Once I ask for the data to start flowing, it's like an open faucet.

I can understand the first 4 character but then I don't.

```
53 31 5C B5 61 99 AB 8B A9 85 91 89 55 85 (Hex)
S  1  This is the echo to say 'starting'
      5C B5 61 99 AB 8B A9 85 91 89 55 85 (Hex)
```

This is the data I need and how it was sent. I can sniff it on the network monitor.

```
83 49 92 65533 97 65533 65533 65533 65533 (dec)
```

I have tried various methods, but currently:

```java
Socket socket=new Socket(ipAddress , portNumber);       //Create Socket
inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream); // Tried (inputStream,"UTF-8")

stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();

public static StringBuffer  recMsg(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader, StringBuffer stringBuffer) throws IOException {
    int x;
    stringBuffer.setLength(0);
    while(true)
    {
        x=inputStreamReader.read();
        stringBuffer.append((char)x);
        //System.out.println("Ready to read:2 "+ inputStreamReader.ready());
        if (stringBuffer.length() >= 500) break;
        if (!inputStreamReader.ready()) break;    //
    }
    System.out.println("Response "+ stringBuffer);
    System.out.println(" --- ");
    return stringBuffer;
}
```

PS in Python I just used

```py
s.connect((host, port))
s.recv(2048)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how data is being sent from the server at the other end of the socket. If you are just sending raw bytes then we need to read it differently than If you were sending a text in the ASCII character set. Note that if you are sending ASCII characters then you might want to be using `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "US-ASCII");`.

Comment: You are ignoring end of stream on the `Reader`. `ready()` is not a test for end of stream: it has few correct uses, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: `inputStreamReader.read()` will return `-1` on EOF, eg: `while ((x=inputStreamReader.read()) != -1) { stringBuffer.append((char)x); if (stringBuffer.length() >= 500) break; }`

Comment: This is the actual data it uses.
53 31 5C B5 61 99 AB 8B A9 85 91 89 55 85 (Hex)
The server is a Dataq module. There are no end of message characters.

It just sends in blocks of 4 to 204 words, depending on the acquisition rate.

It uses TCP/IP Push flag set. 

The data a believe is UTF-8. The data uses 2 words combined to provide the actual number and syncing. each word could be 00 to FF.
The 65533 (FFFD) that the reader is pumping out is wrong. The FF and FD do not even make sense. 

I am obviously doing something wrong. The data is there but i'm not accessing it correctly.

Comment: The Reader. ready() seems to work on the shorter setup dialog but i will use the ((x=inputStreamReader.read()) != -1). The EOF does not actually exist in this scenario. 
i came back to it this morning and it's still sending data to the network. I'm just not listening...

Comment: The payload from Microsoft network monitor. (It's great and free)
C9 83 2B 83 31 83 39 8B 19 89 1B 87 3D 85 91 83 FD 81 C5 81 29 C1 5C B5 37 9B 35 8F 71 89 EF 85 DB 83 43 83 59 83 53 8B 2D 89 35 87 51 85 AB 83 15 83 E1 81 2D C1 5C B5 49 9B 55 8F 93 89 17 87 0D 
Ascii
É+19..=ýÅ)Á\µ75qïÛCYS-5Q«.á-Á\µIU..

Comment: Non Data payload
00 4C 30 30 45 30 30 30 45 30 30 31 45 30 30 32 45 30 30 33 45 30 30 34 45 30 30 35 45 30 30 36 45 30 30 37 45 30 30 38 45 30 30 39 45 30 30 41 45 30 30 42 45 30 30 43 45 30 30 44 45 30 30 45 45 30 30 46 0A

Comment: Equivalent to 
.L00E000E001E002E003E004E005E006E007E008E009E00AE00BE00CE00DE00EE00F.

Comment: P.S. I have spent literal days reading up on sockets and searching for solutions. The only way to learn is to read and work it out but I am very stuck. Thanks for helping

Comment: Hello @user207421. I Tried the while ((x=inputStreamReader.read()) != -1). It hangs when it reaches the end of the message. inputStreamReader.ready() goes false at this time. There is no EOF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256477/tcp-socket-on-java-any-byte-128-is-received-as-65533

Comment: I've found something usefull. The 65533 is a  "Unicode replacement character" used when a value can't be represented as a real Unicode character. Working on getting integers back instead of characters.

Comment: I have made progress . The big change is to use x=inputStream.read(); instead of the reader. This way the Read does not try to interpret the message into unicode.

Comment: `public static void  recMsg(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        int x;
        int loop = 0;
        while (inputStreamReader.ready())
        {
            x=inputStream.read();
            msgFifo.add(x);
            loop +=1;
            if (loop >= 2048) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Response:-" + msgFifo.toString() + "-:");
    }`

Comment: Thats messy. Whats the best way to add code to a comment. I tried `code in backticks` (above) and ``` lang-js ```